# how to create a hover effect for Div class and ID inside the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create next/prev button similar to flexslider default button.

But I want to do that using div and classes.

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/riffaz/ykt8W/)

My mark up is shown below:

```
<div class="dirnav">
    <div id="next"> Next </div>
    <div id="prev" > Prev </div>
</div>
```

1. Default, the arrows must be invisible.
2. When hover the `.dirnav` the arrows must come inside from left and
   right.

How can I do this ?

[EDIT: JSFIDDLE LINK UPDATED]

Comment: it ask username password in fiddle

Comment: ha? that's a public fiddle [link]http://jsfiddle.net/riffaz/ykt8W/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code for elements

```
.dirnav {overflow: hidden;}
#next {margin-left: -30px;}
#prev {margin-right: -30px;}
.dirnav:hover #prev,
.dirnav:hover #next{margin: 0;}
```

Comment: but how to make that right side arrow slide from right side, and left side arrow slide from left using `-webkit-transition`?

Comment: #prev,#next{-webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
-moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
-ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
-o-transition: all 200ms ease;
transition: all 200ms ease;}